# Locating Zeros of a complex-valued polynomial in the first quadrant

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

For the complex-valued polynomial $p(z) = z^4 + z^3 + 4z^2 + 3z + 7$, I want to locate the number of zeros that lie in each quadrant. As zeros are either all real or occur in conjugate pairs, it's enough to consider the 1st quadrant where a quarter of a circle centered at the origin for a sufficiently large radius is considered. ($x$-intercept at $R$ and the $y$-intercept at $iR$)

[image]

By the **Argument Principle**, number of zeros that lies inside $C= C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3$ is given by
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_{i=1}^{3} \Delta_{C_i} \text{arg}(f(z)),$$
where $\Delta_{C_i}\text{arg}(f(z))$ denotes the change in the argument over the curve $C_i$ for $i=1,2,$ and $3$.

It has already been figured out that there are no real or imaginary zeros.
The question I have is in finding the change in the argument on $C_3$.

**My Approach :** Taking $z=iy$ and separating real and imaginary parts yields
$$f(y)=p(iy)=(y^4-4y^2+7) + i y (3- y^2) .$$
Now
$$\text{arg}(f(z)) = \text{tan}^{-1} \bigg\{ \frac{y (\sqrt{3}-y) (\sqrt{3}+y)}{(y^2-2-\sqrt{3}i) (y^2-2+\sqrt{3}i)} \bigg\}$$
Here onwards, I've got stuck. Any help in accomplishing the task is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it required to use complex analysis?  [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) does this (especially quickly if you have determined there are no real or imaginary roots).

Comment: Also, "locate the number of zeros" is an awkward phrase.  You probably either want a count of the number of zeroes.  Locating a root would require isolating a root more precisely than "somewhere in the first quadrant".  Also, how do you want to count repeated roots?

Comment: @EricTowers, thank you for the comment. There are only 4 roots; either two in the first quadrant or two in the second; or one in each quadrant. It's already being figured out that there are neither real nor purely imaginary roots. I want to find out which scenario is possible.

Comment: There's an algebraic formula for the roots of a quartic. This polynomial has a root in each quadrant but the working is best carried out by computer.

Comment: $\Re f >0, y \ge 0$ so the change in argument is at most $\pi$ though with a careful analysis you can reduce that to at most $\pi/2$ and even lower (for $R \to \infty$ you go to zero) (geometrically you start on the positive real axis, wander in the first quadrant until $\sqrt 3$ when you return to the positive axis so the change there is zero and then you do the same in the fourth quadrant eventually at infinity returning so the limit is zero again); since it is fairly trivial by integration to show that the change in argument on the quarter circle is $2\pi$, there is one zero per quadrant

Comment: @Conrad, thank you for the comment. Could you pls provide an answer. The tool I want to use is the "Argument Principle".

Comment: done as requested

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $|z| >3, |p(z)| >0$ by the triangle inequality, while $\Re p(iy) >0, y \in \mathbb R$ and $p(x)>0, x \ge 0$ so to compute the number of roots in the first quadrant it is enough to estimate the change in argument on the curve above for $R>3$.

On $C_2$ the change in argument is $\Im \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac {p'(Re^{i\theta})iRe^{i\theta}d\theta}{p(Re^{i\theta})}$ which clearly converges to $2\pi$ for $R \to \infty$.

On $C_1$ the change in argument is zero.

On $C_3$ the change in argument is at most $\pi$ in absolute value since $\Re p(iy)>0$ means $|\arg p(iy)| < \pi/2$  (we can easily show that for large $R$ it goes to zero but we do not need that).

Putting the above together we get that for large enough $R$ the change of argument of $p$ on the closed curve above is between $\pi-\delta$ and $3\pi+\delta$ where we can choose $\delta$ as small as we want for large $R$

This gives that the number of zeroes in the first quadrant is between $1/2-\epsilon$ and $3/2+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon=\delta/(2\pi)$ small enough, so said number being an integer, it must be $1$ and we are done!

Comment: Thank you. Couple of questions, can you pls tell me how do you decide on $3$ in $|z|  > 3$ and change in the argument is what you have taken. The tools I'm aware of are Argument's principle and Rouche's theorem.

Comment: At $|z|=3, |z^4|$ overpowers the rest of the terms hence $|p(z)|>0$ from then on, though it is not that important since we are interested in $|z|=R$ for large $R$ so the change in argument on the quarter circle is close to $2\pi$ using the integral formula for it; the whole point of the argument method is to ensure that the change of the argument on some closed curve divided by $2\pi$ can take only one integral value and since we know it is an integer, than it must be that and simple estimates like the above are usually enough, though of course more precise ones may be needed but not here